# CSS - Table cell layout exceeding height in Firefox/IE

Tags: css, html, web, css-tables

Given the following code

```
<div style="border:solid 5px orange;width:400px;height:400px">
<div style="display:table;border:solid 1px red;width:100%;height:100%">
    <div style="display:table-row;border:solid 1px blue">
        <div style="display:table-cell;border:solid 1px green;height:100%">
            <div style="height:100%;background:yellow;overflow-y:auto">CONTENT
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>sss
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display:table-row;border:solid 1px blue">
        <div style="display:table-cell;border:solid 1px green;height:100px">
            <div>INPUT</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Chrome correctly sizes the CONTENT area by the available size for the table cell while Firefox and IE increase the size of the table cell to fit the content.
How can I make FF/IE behave like Chrome?

Example in Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/2p6Jx/

**UPDATE :** I cannot use fixed height, the table should change according to it's parent element height and width

**Update 2:** adding `display:-moz-stack` solved the issue in FF, now it is just IE (http://jsfiddle.net/2p6Jx/3/)

Answer (score 0):

I change your code and it works in IE/FF/chrome.

```
<div style="border:solid 5px orange;width:400px;height:400px">
    <div style="display:table;border:solid 1px red;width:100%;height:100%">
       <div style="display:table-row;height:300px;width:100%;">
            <div style="display:table-cell;">
                <div style="background:yellow;overflow-y:auto;height:300px;">
                    CONTENT
                    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>sss
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>
        <div style="display:table-row;height:100px;width:100%;">
            <div style="display:table-cell;border:solid 1px green;height:100px">
                <div>INPUT</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But I need to avoid fixed height.I will update my question.

Comment: Do you have another idea? :)